# SQL Server: how can I count values in one field different from another, with multiple values for same identifier?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables with one common column, and an identifying value that can be duplicate (several observations of same document).

An example:

**TableA**:

```
A_identifier | Value
-------------+-------
1            | A
1            | B
```

**TableB**:

```
B_identifier | A_identifier | Value
-------------+--------------+-------
1            | 1            | A
2            | 1            | B
3            | 1            | B
4            | 1            | C
```

The above example illustrates the type of situation I am looking for in my data - we have a case in `TableA` with multiple values, of which some are the same in `TableB` and some are not. So `TableA.Value` and `TableB.Value` represent the same concept.

I want to know for each `TableA.A_identifier`, how many rows of `TableB` have different values than `TableA.Value`. If there was only one observation per `A_identifier`, this could be solved with a `not`, but the multiple possible values prevent this.

What I have thought about doing is something like this (which does not work):

```
select distinct 
    b.B_identifier, a.A_identifier 
from 
    TableB b
join 
    TableA a in b.A_identifer = a.A_identifier and b.Value != a.Value
```

While the query technically works, it returns the wrong result - it counts all the cases where the values in `TableA` and `TableB` are different in a given row. However, I want it to only count the values in `TableB` which are not present at all in `TableA` for each `A_identifier`.

I tried replacing the `!=` with `not in` which is what I would do for a static parameter. This syntax is not supported.

I hope my question makes sense, and that somebody can help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: could you post expected result for your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query if it works for you,

```
SELECT  COUNT(b.A_identifier)
FROM    TableB b
        LEFT JOIN TableA a
            ON b.A_identifier = a.A_identifier
                AND b.Value = a.Value
WHERE   a.A_identifier IS NULL -- filters out inexisting value
        AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM TableA c
                    WHERE b.A_identifier = c.A_identifier) -- shows only  A_identifier 
                                                           -- that is present in TableA
```

However, if you want to get the count for each `Value`

```
SELECT  b.A_identifier, b.Value, TOTAL_COUNT = COUNT(b.A_identifier)
FROM    TableB b
        LEFT JOIN TableA a
            ON b.A_identifier = a.A_identifier
                AND b.Value = a.Value
WHERE   a.A_identifier IS NULL
        AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM TableA c
                    WHERE b.A_identifier = c.A_identifier) 
GROUP   BY b.A_identifier, b.Value
```

Comment: The first query worked for me with a minor change - I added `a.Identifer` in the select clause, and a `group by` in the end, and a `distinct`in the count - which gave me exactly what I needed - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT EXISTS`

```
select t1.A_identifier, count(t2.value)
from TableA t1
left join TableB t2 on t1.A_identifier = t2.A_identifier and
                  NOT EXISTS (
                          select 1 
                          from TableA t3 
                          where t3.A_identifier = t2.A_identifier and 
                                t3.Value = t2.Value
                 )
group by t1.A_identifier
```

Comment: Thank you - this answer was just as good as the accepted one, minor modifications to get exactly what I needed. I accepted the other as it was first.

Comment: @ipoga glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

How about the following SQL?

```
select distinct TableA.A_identifier, 
  (select count(*) from TableB 
   where TableB.A_identifier = TableA.A_identifier
   and not exists( 
        select * from TableA where A_identifier = TableB.A_identifier
        and Value = TableB.Value) 
  ) 
    as TableB_Rows
from TableA
```